# Expand fields on artisan make:auth

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-artisan

I have generated Laravel's authentication code using

php artisan make:auth

The auto-generated registration form provides the following fields:
Name, Email, and Password.

I'm trying to add First Name, Last Name instead of just Name. I've successfully created the DB Table and the form(view) with the fields. When I test and register a user the password and email fields are saved but not the First Name and Last Name.

My guess is that I'm missing a file that I have not modified.

What page defines the fields that get written into the database?

This is my validator and auth code in authcontroller:

```
 /**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        'first_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'last_name' => 'required|max:255',
        'email' => 'required|email|max:255|unique:users',
        'password' => 'required|min:8|confirmed',
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return User
 */

protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'first_name' => $data['first_name'],
        'last_name' => $data['last_name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

If I change 'first_name' to 'name' on the controller and the database table it does save. Validator works well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to you `AuthController` which should be in `app/Http/Controllers/Auth`.

In there you will need to change the `validator()` and `create()` methods to include `firstname` and `lastname` fields.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Ross. I've already made those modifications. The fields exist in the database but they won't save. If I change first_name to name in both controller and data base it does save.

Answer (score 0):

The modification that I was missing was on the user.php file:

```
<?php
namespace App;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    /**
    * The attributes that are mass assignable.
    *
    * @var array
    */
    protected $fillable = [
    'first_name', 'last_name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];
}
```

The fields that I added needed to be included as protected $fillable. I made that change and everything is working.